# make jquery wait for completion of for loop before continuing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am using a bit of code to highlight a specific element for a short amount of time upon page load (assuming a specific parameter is passed in the url params).

The code has a starting colour and then iterates through back to white.

When that has completed I want to set the back ground colour again. (or remove the inline style attribute that is created).

What appears to be happening is that the code to do the final colour change is executed before the iteration has completed.

I tried using promises, deffering etc but no luck. My latest attempt was to move the iteration code in to a separate JS file and calling that via AJAX and putting the last colour change in to the complete of that call. Even that fires the code before iteration has finished! can anyone help?? this is my code:

Code to glow background of my div: (held in flashfaq.js)

```
function a() {
        $('.faqTitle').first().css('backgroundColor', 'hsl(45,100%,50%');
        var d = 10;
        for (var i = 50; i <= 100; i = i + 0.1) {
            d += 5;
            (function(ii, dd) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.faqTitle').first().css('backgroundColor', 'hsl(45,100%,' + ii + '%)');
                }, dd);
            })(i, d);
        };

    }
```

AJAX to call this:

```
    function showSpecificFaq() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/../scripts/flashFAQ.js",
            dataType: "script",
            complete: function(data) {
                 $('.faqTitle').first().css('backgroundColor', '');
            }
        });
    }
```

I was thinking that the complete would only fire once the code in flashFAQ had finished, but it doesn't seem to be happening that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, creating so many timers is not good for performance. I changed the script so there is a function that changes the color once and schedules its own call with next color. After the final color is reached, it restores initial color and stops making timeouts.

```
changeColor(50);

function changeColor(l){
    if (l > 100) {
        //a condition that terminates the cycle and restores original color
        $('.faqTitle').css('backgroundColor', '#f00');
    } else {        
        $('.faqTitle').css('backgroundColor', 'hsl(45,100%,' + l + '%)');
        //scheduling next change
        setTimeout(function(){
            changeColor(l + 1);
        }, 100);
    }   
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/GHrKN/

This is how you can do cycles with timeouts in general. For style animation, JQuery has [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. I'm not very familiar with this, but I think you could use it here